# Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type string | number can't be used to index type

Tags: typescript

It's my first post on Stack Overflow, so i'll try to explain the best I can ! I have this JSON file that is nammed phrases.JSON :

```
{
  "start": {
    "affirmative": [
      some strings
    ],
    "interrogative": [
     some strings
    ]
  },
  "mid": [
    some strings
  ]
}
```

So I import it in another file as phrases, with `import phrases from '../utils/phrases.json'`, and declare in modules.d.ts with that.

```
declare module '*.json' {
  const data: any
  export default data
}
```

I made an interface in the file where I imported phrases.json, just like that :

```
interface Phrases {
  [key: string]: TypePhrases | string[]
  start: TypePhrases
  mid: string[]
}
interface TypePhrases {
  [key: string]: string[]
  affirmative: string[]
  interrogative: string[]
}
```

In my class, I created a function :

```
private getPhrases(position: string | number) {
    return phrases[position]
  }
```

So if I call this function in my class, i want to get the start object if I give the string 'start', or the string array if I give 'mid', just like that :

```
const MID_STRING: string = 'mid'
console.log(this.getPhrases(MID_STRING)[0])
```

But in my return function, I get this error :

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
>   'string | number' can't be used to index type '{ "start": {
>   "affirmative": string[]; "interrogative": string[]; }; "mid":
>   string[]; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string'
>   was found on type '{ "start": { "affirmative": string[];
>   "interrogative": string[]; }; "mid": string[]; }'.

Could you help me please ? I tried so much things, I don't know how to resolve it... Thanks !

Comment: How is `phrases` defined ?

Comment: The post is edited with the informations

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of the import object will be determined by the object  in the `.json` file not by the types you defined (there is no link I can see between the two). Also the definition `declare module '*.json'` is not what the compiler is using since it finds the file on disk.

The problem you are having is really simple though. Typescript can't prove that `phrase` is a valid key to index `phrases`.

You can use type assertions to actually use the types you defined:

```
private getPhrases(position: string) {
    return (phrases as Phrases)[position]
}

m() {
    const MID_STRING = 'mid'
    var a = this.getPhrases(MID_STRING); // a is TypePhrases | string[]
    if (a instanceof Array) { // must use type guard to index
        a[0]
    }
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgCwE4EMIFMIwLwwN4BQMxMARNCklKQFz5EmOkoBmLAlkgLYpTsBu6WjADaDRhLKlxEgLoAaGU3Zgo6JEhABzXgKF0xkyaWlGYsmQF9FTLuwAmww0ZMyLlggRVqkLFMHQYAAVkNEx6YhEAa3QATzpoJBUtWToAFVi4dBDUDCwAHxhE5JELYgoqdMzs0LyGO3sEqCSwLVKCD291PwCYDKycsKxCSJj4oubk1ImWtrKYVg5uXUEm2fbiLo1tFfQ1kvdPYAAbNCwADQiSOCT+XkCtdChBvIAKOBAIdj5wfdaASiukiQTwArkgwDB3rVwmhgjCIP8RB8vj8wPNiB4ZFxXoCRkZQJBYABZACSABEAPoAZTSACVSQA5ADiOBgAHIGuylCQ7kgFmyoAh2BAAHSPZ4I15kqm0hks-4AbhgAHoVQKRX1qi9woViq0NkZ2CwoSgYCoKGAAiATQBBDQoWJ41Xqrig6Awd2BKDVGBaUGUewwKAgc1gezoAAePMkKBEAAYMRIPIwPJYgA)

You could also take a better safer option and use `keyof` coupled with generics to actually get the correct type of the value in the object. This is possible only if you generally use constants.

```
private getPhrases<K extends keyof typeof phrases>(position: K) {
    return phrases[position]
}

m() {
    const MID_STRING = 'mid' // no string annotation, MID_STRING is typed as 'mid'
    this.getPhrases(MID_STRING)[0]; // ts knows this returns string[] and we can index iderctly into it
}
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgCwE4EMIFMIwLwwN4BQMxMARNCklKQFz5EmOkoBmLAlkgLYpTsBu6WjADaDRhLKlxEgLoAaGU3Zgo6JEhABzXgKF0xkyaWlGYsmQF9FTLuwAmww0ZMyLlggWAAbNFgAa9IxwSAK86DBa6FAACshomAA8ANIw6AAeamD2WADW6ACeICwwUAVw6MXw8RgQAHwAFHAgEOx84HTJAJRBRkjRAK5IYNWotSLNre1gFoweMlwNPYRmoJCwALIAkgAiAPoAygAqAEpbAHIA4jgwAOR29rcwAPTPMGAgMNChYFowKGAPlBdOB5DBtvtjmcrjB2FgyhV7P8sPcHLclCQoAg4QA6KKxGqYBoQw6nC6XLoiAAMsgA3C83lA8h8AO7w7FYfpQIaQL5QH5aESyf7ZGAsiLAAGw7IZWH2dTAKDeArSqCfNpWAiWIA)

If you have a `string` you want to use to index a type you can also assert the string is a `keyof` the type. This is of course not type safe but sometimes necessary:

```
private getPhrases(position: string) {
    return phrases[position as keyof typeof phrases]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The array index should be an integer, not a string

```
private getPhrases(phrase:string, position: number) {
    return phrase[position]
  }
```

and

```
const MID_STRING: string = 'mid'
console.log(this.getPhrases(MID_STRING,0))
```

Comment: Where is phrases here ??